# How can i write Angular Service to get a particular product based on Product ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angular-services

I have JSON API which has 9 products how can i write service to get a single product based on productID(JSON has PRODUCTID for each products). Here is my JSON LINK https://api.myjson.com/bins/5a403 I know how to use routeparams to get a particular ID too all i need is rewrite the service to get a single product

```
 var app=angular.module('myApp');
   app.service('productservice', function($http){
        this.productlists=function(index)
        {
           return $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/5a403")
            .success(function(data) {
            return data;
         })
          .error(function(data) {
          return data;
         });
        };
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return `promise` itself from the `service`.

```
var app=angular.module('myApp');
 app.service('productservice', function($http){

    this.productlists=function(productId) {
       var _promise = $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/5a403")
                  .then(function(response){                        
                      // assign the product by filtering based on productId
                      var requiredObj = response.filter(function(product){
                         if(product.productId == productId){
                            return product;
                         }
                      });

                    return requiredObj;
                  });
       return _promise;
    };
  });
```

And in your `controller`, you can get the `UIstateparams`, from that, you can extract `id` => pass it to your service like this.

```
$scope.yourMethod = function(id){
    productservice.productlists(id).then(function(data){
       $scope.yourModel = data;
    });
}
```

I think that should do the trick.

Comment: But that will return me all 10 products what i need is to fetch detail of a particular product

Comment: Bro that will return the 0th product only i want to get via UIstateparams how can i send that stateparams to service this is how my code looks like                                               app.controller('singleproductcontroller',['$scope','$stateParams','productservice',function($scope,$stateParams,productservice)productservice.productlists().then(function(response)
  $scope.count=0;
  $scope.products=response.data[$stateParams.id-1];           }]);

Answer (score 0):

```
var app=angular.module('myApp');
   app.service('productservice', function($http){
        this.productlists=function(index)
        {
           return $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/5a403")
            .success(function(data) { 

             // lets assume productId=1;
            data=data.filter(function(item){
               if(item.productId==productId){
                 return item;
               }
            })
            return data;
         })
          .error(function(data) {
          return data;
         });
        };
      });
```

NOTE : You can **return promise**(as already shown in other answer) and use **.filter** on **data object** in controller also.